# How to call associations dynamically in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to fetch associations of a model dynamically. For ex;

```
model1 has_many model2s
model1 has_many model3s
```

normally i can do `x.model2s` or `x.model3s`. But what if i dont know which association is wanted. Is there any snippet like : `x["model2s"]` to call associations dynamically?

Thanks
Çağdaş.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do `x.send("model#{i}s")` assuming you have the number saved in `i` or just `x.send(foo)` if you have the full name as string or symbol saved in `foo`.

Documentation:

- [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)
- [Object#public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

Comment: Be warned, if this is the result of user input, you could do something dangerous.  Imagine: `x.send("#{method}")`.  If method was created by user input as "destroy" ...   So you should somehow limit the possible input values.

Comment: @DGM: `x.send(foo) if x.class.reflections[foo]`

Comment: downvoting this in lite of lulalala's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is safer as it limits to association methods only:

```
x.association("model#{i}s").scope
```